# How does android boot and shows notifications with full encryption but without pre-boot authentication

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography, privacy, android

i have android 5.1 (motorola moto g xt1039). i encrypted the phone and set screen password. then

after every password change i can choose one of an two options:

- 'require the password at startup'
- 'no thanks'

when i choose the first one, phone asks for password before booting. when i choose the second option phone boots without the password but require password to unlock the screen. i'm aware that android can mount dummy temporary `/data` filesystem only to show nice UI.

but when the second option is chosen, phone after booting but before receiving my password can show notifications of new incoming emails or messenger messages. and we are talking about android 5 (before file-based encryption)

so how does my fully encrypted android, without asking for my password, knows:

- that i have installed gmail or messenger
- my email or messenger password
- that i have enabled notifications for gmail and messanger

how does it work without my password when it's supposed to be fully encrypted? or when i decide not to use require the password during the boot, the full disk encryption just uses the default password? if so, is it secure at all, does it still protect data of a stolen phone (i know that user password together with hardware based key/chip is required to decrypt the disk)?

again, the scenario:

- reboot encrypted phone with screen-lock password set
- wait until it boots (don't provide any password)
- send an email or a messenger message from another phone
- the encrypted phone shows notification about incoming message but it never received the password to decrypt the disk

Comment: If you pull the battery, then plug it back in 24h later and try to boot it, does it ask for your password _then_? If so, it sounds like it's storing the encryption keys in plaintext on the device, which is the digital version of putting a key under your doormat. Frankly, _if_ they **didn't tell you very clearly that this would happen** when you chose between the 2 options, I'd bet they're doing something _quite_ similar even if you choose the other option. (I'd love to see a security lab report on this...)

Comment: Relevant: https://blog.g3rt.nl/android-lollipop-encryption-user-interface-flaw.html and https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk